# Use concurrently in yarn with wildcards

Tags: yarnpkg, concurrently

I would like to have in the scripts of package.json for yarn something like: `"start": "concurrently yarn:start:*"`.

Using npm, one could call `concurrently` with wildcards like this:

```
"start": "concurrently npm:start:*",
"start:cmd1": "one_cmd.sh",
"start:cmd2": "other_cmd.sh",
"start:cmd3": "another_one.sh"
```

Switching to yarn it would work to call `yarn run` explicitly each time:

```
"start": "concurrently \"yarn run start:cmd1\" \"yarn run start:cmd2\" \"yarn run start:cmd3\""
```

Is there a shorter way and especially one that would use wildcards to automatically start all scripts matching the name pattern?

**Update:** Was unintentionally using yarn 3.0.2 instead of 1.11.22, where it works as intended. Would still like to know about concurrently in yarn/berry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it, you just need to wrap your pattern script into double quotes. Also you need to add `run` before `start` as yarn does not recognize more complex script as basic. I believe what you need is something like this:

```
start: "concurrently \"yarn run start:*\""
// or ...
start: "concurrently \"yarn run start:cmd*\""
```

You can check more complex examples of concurrently patterns [in docs](https://github.com/open-cli-tools/concurrently#usage) if you need.